# Block a command

Tags: sudo, root

I don't want any admin users in my system to execute the following command other than root.

**"sudo cp /etc/sudoers "**

Is it possible to block it for admin users only?

I have tried lot but didn't get anything?

Comment: The line: *Is it possible to block it for admin users only?* seems a bit strange, non-admins won'be able to run with `sudo` anyway?

Comment: Nope. Blocking a single command isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't trust someone to have full shell access on your system, don't give them shell access at all.

You want to stop `cp` command what about other commands that acts like `cp` , what about if admins use **scp** command .

Am not saying its impossible to block this command , but a play around trick will defeat your goal .

Comment: "Am not saying its impossible to block this command" yes it is. Any sudo account will be able to re-do any alterations root made. The only way to do this is by "obscurity" and that is not going to stop an *informed* user.

Comment: what about changing permissions on commands binaries

Comment: I can change those back if I have a sudo account. All I need to do is `sudo su` and provide my sudo password.

Comment: then its not impossible , but you can reverse changes

Comment: That is doing it "by obscurity". That never works. It will even make things worse: I reset the change back after I am done with whatever I want to do and you will never find out I did... No, changing admin pwd and NOT handing it out is the sane option.